# Why the buffer geometry column in the GeoDataFrame is in point form although it's actually in polygon form?

Tags: geometry, geopandas, buffer, geopackage, geodataframe

I wanted to create a 1.5km buffer for each geocoded point. Here's the screenshot of the geocoded points dataframe.
[image]

So I overwrote the geometry column using the code below:

```
shopping_centres['geom'] = shopping_centres.apply(lambda row: row['geom'].buffer(1500), axis = 1)
shopping_centres.head()
```

[image]

Then, I saved it as a new layer in an existing GeoPackage layer.

```
shopping_centres.to_file(DATA_DIRECTORY / "shopping_centres.gpkg", layer = "buffers")
```

However, when I tried to read the buffer layer again in a new notebook, the geometry is in point form instead of polygon as shown in the image below the code.

```
shopping_centre_buffers = geopandas.read_file(DATA_DIRECTORY / "shopping_centres.gpkg", layers = "buffers")
shopping_centre_buffers.head()
```

[image]

Where is my mistake? I tried to create a new column for buffer (set it as the geometry) and keep the original geometry column but I couldn't save it because I had two geometry columns.

EDIT: To answer BERA's recent question, here's how I did it:

```
shopping_centres['geom'] = shopping_centres['geometry']
shopping_centres = shopping_centres.set_geometry('geom')
shopping_centres = shopping_centres.drop('geometry', axis = 1)
shopping_centres.head()
```

EDIT NO.2: Here's how I geocoded the shopping centre addresses:

```
import geopandas
geocoded_shopping_centres = geopandas.tools.geocode(
    shopping_centres["addr"],
    provider = "nominatim",
    user_agent = "mygislesson",
    timeout = 10
)

shopping_centres = geocoded_shopping_centres.join(shopping_centres)
shopping_centres
```

Comment: Have you renamed the geometry with https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.rename_geometry.html BEFORE you buffered, not just rename() ?

Comment: @BERA About the "geom", I created a new column called geom and set it as the geometry. The original geometry column was then dropped. Ignore it because redo the whole thing using the original geometry column. I tried renaming it using rename.geometry and the result is still the same.

Comment: @BERA I've just edited the post so you can see how I did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `read_file` call. You use parameter `layers="buffers"` instead of `layer="buffers"`. So:

```
shopping_centre_buffers = geopandas.read_file(
    DATA_DIRECTORY / "shopping_centres.gpkg",
    layers="buffers",
)
```

Should be

```
shopping_centre_buffers = geopandas.read_file(
    DATA_DIRECTORY / "shopping_centres.gpkg",
    layer="buffers",
)
```

If the `layer` parameter is not specified, the "first" layer encountered is read, which is apparently your point layer.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer! Thank you for noticing it I completely overlooked the typo. But I wonder why the geopackage still has a geometry in point form? Because the geometry column had been overwritten with the buffer.

Comment: Quote from your question: `Then, I saved it as a new layer in an existing GeoPackage layer.` -> As you save it as a new layer, you now have 2 layers in the GeoPackage: the original points in one layer and the buffers on them in a seperate one.